# Problem of create Pandas Dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have create a Dataframe from a dictionary like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': 'Ford Motor', 'AssetType': 'Common Stock', 'Exchange': 'NYSE'}

records = []
statement = {}
    
for key, value in data.items():
    statement = {}
    statement[key] = value

    records.append(statement)
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

If I do this way, the output look like this:

```
    Name        AssetType     Exchange
0   Ford Motor  NaN           NaN
1   NaN         Common Stock  NaN
2   NaN         NaN           NYSE
```

I want the values on the first row and the result look like this:

```
    Name    AssetType    Exchange
0   Ford    Common Stock NYSE
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])` ?

Comment: Are you sure you want `AssetType` to be `Motor` and not `'Common Stock'`?

Comment: sorry, typo mistakes. I want the asset type to be common stock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `data` inside a list `[]` when creating dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': 'Ford Motor', 'AssetType': 'Common Stock', 'Exchange': 'NYSE'}

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Name     AssetType Exchange
0  Ford Motor  Common Stock     NYSE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are *a lot* of ways you might want to turn data (dict, list, nested list, etc) into a dataframe.  Pandas also includes many creation methods, some of which will overlap, making it hard to remember how to create dfs from data.  Here are a few ways you could do this for your data:

- `df = pd.DataFrame([data])`
- `df = pd.Series(data).to_frame().T`
- `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index").T`
- `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index=[0])`

imo, `from_dict` is the least intuitive (I never get the arguments right on the first try).  I find focusing on one construction method to be more memorable than using a different one each time; I use `pd.DataFrame(...)` and `from_records(...)` the most.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. In the dictionary, there have 3 pairs of key and value. If I only want to select 2 pairs of key and value to create a dataframe, may I know what can I do?

Comment: Several ways - if your data is small, just create a dataframe, and pass in the list of columns you want to keep to the original, something like `subset_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c != "Name"]; df = df[subset_cols]`